# spring webclient with ssl throws NPE

Tags: java, spring, webclient, flux, reactive

i'd like to create a normal spring webclient to continuously read a stream. that stream is from a https page.

i found some "tutorials" that should show how to do that with spring webclient but they don't.
either they are outdated or they are just wrong, or a lot of information is missing, especially about the used classes.

something like HttpClient.create()... is a PITA without knowing which exact dependency to use!

my current testing code is this:

```
package chatclient;

import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class SslWebClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                    .forClient()
                    .build();

            ReactorClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector();
//            HttpClient.create();

            WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                    .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
                    .build();


            Flux<String> stringFlux = webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri("https://www.google.com")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class);
            stringFlux.subscribe(System.out::println);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

as expected it throws the NPE as i don't know how to create a httpclient.create() with a sslcontext like mentioned here [Spring WebClient - SSL configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61773397/spring-webclient-ssl-configuration)
because i just dont know what httpclient class is used here - it is not the one from: apache, jdk, jetty

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, here is the "fixed" code:

```
package chatclient;

import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

public class SslWebClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                    .forClient()
                    .build();

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

            WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                    .clientConnector(httpConnector)
                    .build();

            Flux<String> stringFlux = webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri("https://www.google.com")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class);
            stringFlux.subscribe(System.out::println);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

it requires:

```
compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-handler', version: '4.1.51.Final'
compile group: 'io.projectreactor.netty', name: 'reactor-netty', version: '0.9.11.RELEASE'
```

webclient uses netty, not jetty. then the samples work